# HTML submit form from select but comma separate values in GET

Tags: html, jquery, forms, redirect, drop-down-menu

I have a simple HTML form that has a dropdown.

```
<form method="get">
    <select name="category[]" multiple class="form-control">
        <option value="1">First Value</option>
        <option value="2">Second Value</option>
        <option value="2">Third Value</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Upon submission of this form, it redirects to https://WEBSITE/?category[]=1&category[]=2. How do I have it redirect to https://WEBSITE/?category=1,2

I was looking for a simple solution instead of using jQuery to intercept the form submission, load in every submitted value, comma separate it, and use `window.location.href` to redirect.

Comment: Use `$("select[name=category\[\]]").val().join(",")` to get a comma-delimited list of the categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select multiple class="form-control" onclick="document.getElementById('cat').value=Object.values(this.options).filter(option=>option.selected).map(option=>option.value).join(',')">
    <option value="1">First Value</option>
    <option value="2">Second Value</option>
    <option value="3">Third Value</option>
</select>
<form method="get">
    <input id="cat" type="hidden" name="category" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```